# Send +1 Day on JQuery DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to emit the day after the selected day.

```
$('#toDate').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '#x',
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", //day
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", //year
        monthNames: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
        dayNamesMin: ["Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct"],
        firstDay: 1,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          socket.emit('sockettoDate', $('#x').val());
        }
      });
```

If **'2017-11-16'** selected, I want to emit **'2017-11-17'**. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work for you:

```
$('#toDate').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: '#x',
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", //day
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", //year
    monthNames: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct"],
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var dateup = ('0' + (parseInt(inst.selectedDay) + 1)).slice(-2);
        var monthup = ('0' + (parseInt(inst.selectedMonth) + 1)).slice(-2);
        var newdate = inst.selectedYear+'-'+monthup+'-'+dateup;
        socket.emit('sockettoDate', newdate);
    }
});
```

Comment: It cannot calculate the day after the last day of month. For example if `2017-12-31` selected, result is `2017-12-32`. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are two inputBoxes; But at any time only one would be visible;

I have added a different label so that u can differentiate after date changes;

Tweak it to meet your needs.

```js
$('#toDate').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        altField: '#x',
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", //day
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd", //year
        monthNames: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
        dayNamesMin: ["Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct"],
        firstDay: 1,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {            
            showHideDate(dateText);
        }
      });
 
 function showHideDate(dateText) {
   document.getElementById("defaultDate").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("hiddenDate").style.display = "block";
   let splittedDate = dateText.split("-");
   let nextDay = parseInt(splittedDate[0])+1
   let newDate =  nextDay + '-' + splittedDate[1] + '-' + splittedDate[2];
   
   document.getElementById("newDate").value = newDate;
 }
```

```css
#hiddenDate {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p id="defaultDate">Date: <input type="text" id="toDate"></p>
<p id="hiddenDate">New Date: <input type="text" id="newDate"></p>
```

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I want to send the edited day to server. Anyway, thank you for your time.